# Client side validation of file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file, client-side-validation

I have a form and there I wanna allow to user upload only one type of file. I use **client side validation**, but the file-type validation has not behavior as I would expected. I tried to validation the file type with these two ways:

```
  validates :doc_type, :allow_blank => true, :format => {:with => /\A.*\.(pdf|PDF)\z/, :message => 'must be PDF file.'}
```

and also

```
validates_attachment_content_type :doc_type, :content_type => { :content_type => "application/pdf" }
```

But the error about bad file type is not displayed via **Client side validation**, but as usual validation error.

Exist any way to display the validation error by Client side validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the jquery validate plugin on the client side first, before submitting to your back end. This allows you to validate file types on the front end.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept

Here is a sample, makes "field" required and ending with ".xls" or ".csv".

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      accept: "xls|csv"
    }
  }
});
```

The great thing about using the jquery validation plugin is that it will also make other ciient side validations convenient, like email, password, etc.

Comment: thank you @botbot - would you know how to easily add another validation check for the file size?